# Apache Server Variable ENV is different on the command line when using Drush

Tags: php, apache, drupal, ubuntu, command-line-interface

This problem is occuring with Drupal but can be attributed to a general Apache - PHP configuration. In my configuration file I am determing which database to use by a server variable.

```
if($_SERVER['ENV'] == 'development') {
//Use connection A
} else {
//Use connection B
}
```

In apache I am setting the env like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
//Other normal Apache variables set
SetEnv ENV development
</VirtualHost>
```

In my normal website setting, this works perfectly fine with PHP is accessed through the webserver. But I am trying to run a command using drush, which is on the command line, and it always connects to the wrong database. The problem really is command line php always connects to connection B and I don't think its necessarily drush.

How do I set the ENV to work both on apache on and the command line? The OS is ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Drush doesn't use Apache to run commands, rather it loads and runs the PHP files directly. To set the variable globally on the server you can edit `/etc/environment` and add

```
ENV=development
```

You can read more about setting environment variables in Ubuntu, check out [this help article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Answer (score 1):

The --uri switch will inform Drush of what domain to use in the case that HTTP_HOST is unset at runtime.

example: `drush --uri=http://uri-to-development cc all`

You can add it to the drushrc on each machine so that you don't have to type it every time.

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer,

Apache has its own environment vs the command-line ENV ( run `export`to see the difference ).
Apache also include headers/ENV vars that are meaningful only to a web server ( like `HTTP_REFERER` & `DOCUMENT_ROOT` ) which are meaningless via command-line ( you don't really have a `DOCUMENT_ROOT` when using the shell on a regular basis )

The problem in my opinion, starts when you're adding some `SetEnv` variables in your Apache configuration that you need to also include when you're testing the file via command-line ( such as custom `PATH`(s) etc .. or a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Oracle i.e ... )

The bigger problem is that sometimes you can `SetEnv` variables in your `some-local-websiteX.conf` and some `SetEnv` were defined under the global `httpd.conf`

So I usually do this

#### 1. Print the ENV variables that Apache is using

in my document root I add this small script ( it's in Python but you can adjust it to do the same in PHP )

`File: www/env.cgi`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n"


import os
for e in os.environ:
    print "export {key}='{value}' <br />".format(key=e, value=os.environ[e])
```

#### 2. Creating a custom bash env file

I then copy paste the output in the browser to a local file `~/.bash_apache_env`

#### 3. Running my website via commandline

Every terminal window will reset the environment to the defaults ( unless you have some settings in your `~/.bashr` i.e ofc ), so I'm running the following in each window I need.

```
source ~/.bash_apache_env

# then I can execute
www/index.cgi
www/admin.cgi

# etc ..
```

The #1 & #2 are usually just a one-time thing

Hope it helps...